# Is there any way to find Donald Knuth's undergrad/master's thesis?

Tags: masters, thesis, undergraduate

Just what the title says. As far as I know, Knuth's undergrad thesis was so good that the faculty at his university decided to honor him with both an undergrad degree and a master's automatically.

I wonder if this thesis is available for the public to see. I suppose students at Case Western have full access to it, but I'm unfortunately not one of them. Is there a way to get access to this thesis?

Comment: Do you have a reference that says there _was_ a thesis? I've seen that Case Western awarded him B.S. and M.S. together, but no mention of him having written a B.S. thesis.

Comment: It's not listed on his [C.V. - PDF version](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/vita.pdf) and there's nothing in Case Western's library catalog.

Comment: What about emailing Knuth, the secretary of CWU's CS program, or their library?

Comment: It is impossible to email Knuth directly, because he stopped using email in 1990 http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/email.html I would approach the library directly.

Comment: @ff524 I don't know if there is a thesis but I'd suppose so. Isn't it necessary for graduation in all universities? 

As it's impossible to email Knuth and the time it takes to even get him to read the snail mail is too long, I'll try contacting CWU's library then.

Comment: @Teckizt _Isn't it necessary for graduation in all universities?_ - nope, not necessarily at B.S. and M.S. level.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Finally, I contacted CWU's library and was told by an archivist that Knuth indeed graduated from the Case Institute of Technology with a BSc and an MSc simultaneously in 1960.

However, he didn't need to present a thesis. It was not a graduation requirement at that time.

What a shame!

Comment: No problem :) I was dying to know the answer!

Comment: The faculty voted to give him a Master's degree not because he presented a great undergraduate thesis (there was no such thing, as you said), but because he had been taking mostly graduate (Master's) courses, and doing well at them. (In a recent interview he revealed that it was because he found the graduate courses easier… but whatever it was, it was sufficiently unusual that the faculty had a special vote and did things this way.)